# Rails 3: Ajax and the <%= escape_javaScript(item) %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

*(note that everything works perfectly outside of the Ajax. the submittable class works to submit the form onchange)

So here I've set up a basic sample, for some reason I can't get the <%= escape_javaScript(item) %> to show on the form submit. To better explain, I'll just show my relative code.

index.html.erb

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <%= form_for contact,:remote => true do |f| %>
        <div class="editField">
            <%= f.collection_select :agent_id, get_user_list("agent"), :id, :full_name, {:include_blank => 'None assigned'},:class => "submittable" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div id="agent2">
        <%= contact.agent_id %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

contact_controller.rb

```
def update
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])
        format.js { render }
      end
    end
end
```

update.js.erb

```
$('#agent2').html("<%= escape_javaScript(contact.agent_id) %>");
```

With that set up, I get no response or change to the (div id agent2) but if I have update.js.erb using this code

```
$('#agent2').html("something");
```

The text "something" replaces the current contact.agent_id

I'm beyond confused as to why its not working correctly. I'm using Rails 3.0.3 with ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10], and use Jquery.

Comment: Do you get any console errors or javascript errors (use chrome dev tools/firebug)? Also try using @contact instead of contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are calling the `escape_javascript` helper? It looks like you are just wanting the `agent_id` value to be inside the `#agent2` div. Is that the case? Have you tried just `$('#agent2').html("<%= contact.agent_id %>");`

Typically, when I am using the `escape_javascript` helper method I will pass in a partial so the call will look something like:

```
$('#agent2').html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'partial_name') ) %>");
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

escape_javascript is case sensitive and all lowercase. Can you try:

```
$('#agent2').html("<%= escape_javascript('something') %>");
```